# Can I pop up a dialog box on the IOS Home interface, like AirPods?

Tags: ios

I have a BLE device. When the device sends data to the mobile phone, I want to pop up an information box on the iPhone to display the data. It requires that I can still pop up the window in the background like Airpods. Is there any way to achieve this function?

Answer (score 1):

You could't pop a dialog like AirPods, because It's system private framework! You should use the local notification, then the user can choose to see it or not. Force user to see the dialog on home screen of device isn't recommended by apple. If apple provide the technique, I suppose that it is very likely to be abused!